# HTTP Error 500 when upload file to Google Drive via API V3

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a production app that running almost one year to regularly upload file from Google App Engine (python) to Google Drive using Google Drive API v3.

but today I received lots of error HTTP Error 500.
here's my app engine log:

```
12:44:44.296 Refreshing access_token
12:44:44.985 An error occurred: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json returned "Internal Error">
12:44:45.054 URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json (/base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/1.zzz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py:863)
```

any clue how to fix this error?
is the problem on my side or on Google Drive API side?

any help appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the problem in this error is on Google Drive side. i had the same error . but when i reduce my file size , the error does not appear again.

Comment: my file only few KB (yes, kilo bytes). I think it's only happen like occasionally.